# urlparse Type/Attribute Errors

Tags: python, unicode, urllib

Python 2.7.

I'm sure this is a dumb question but I'm really confused by the type/attribute errors I'm getting from urlsplit.

I'm trying to iterate through a list of unicode urls', splitting and rebuilding them to remove part of the url.

```
new_list = []
for line in list_of_links:
    urlsplit(line)
    new_list.append(line.scheme + '://' + line.netloc + line.path)
```

returns `AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'scheme'`

Encoding each line as utf-8 doesn't work. str(line).scheme returns `'str' object has no attribute 'scheme'`

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`line` is still a str, and strings don't have those methods. `urlparse()` and `urlsplit()` return the `ParseResult`and `SplitResult` named tuple objects respectively. See the docs [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#results-of-urlparse-and-urlsplit). Only these have the `scheme` and `netloc` properties. To use them properly, store the result in a variable, like so:

```
new_list = []
for line in list_of_links:
    urlsplit_result = urlsplit(line)
    new_list.append(urlsplit_result.scheme + '://' + urlsplit_result.netloc + urlsplit_result.path)
```